# Icon design and jagged edges

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I thought I had my ios app icon all settled. I designed in Photoshop and tested in the prescribed sizes and it looks great (resizing in photoshop and saving to .png). I also tested via the "add to home screen" to see how it would look and looks nice and crisp (via a cool little webpage that lets you upload icon and bookmark on your device).

However, when I upload it as the large 1024 x 1024 icon (png) you do via iTunes Connect my shapes look all jagged. At least in the preview you get when initially getting ready to submit a new application.

Wondering what causes this and what I need to take into account as it pertains to how Apple resizes icons for delivery. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What resolution did you design it in?  If you designed it in Photoshop, it is a raster image and I would suggest you design in illustrator as a vector, but at the very minimum make sure your designed resolution is higher than the proportions required for the icon by Itunes.

Comment: I designed it at 1024 x 1024 at 72 dpi and it seemed to scale down fine when I tested. I used vector shapes.

Comment: Vector would be 300dpi, but regardless, if it only scaled up to 1024x1024 you should be fine.  It could be the preview that Apple is generating, I am not familiar with their previews.